# Connect nodes in path statement

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a sequence of nodes which I would like to connect.

The following path specification draws a triangle but connects the coordinates instead of the nodes at those coordinates.

```
\draw (0,0)
    +(90:1cm) node {1} to
    +(210:1cm) node {2} to
    +(330:1cm) node {3} to
    +(90:1cm);
```

What I would like instead would be something like the following code which connects the nodes and not the center positions stated in the path.

```
\draw (0,0)
    +(90:1cm) node[name=a]  {}
    +(210:1cm) node[name=b] {}
    +(330:1cm) node[name=c] {};
\foreach \from/\to in {a/b, b/c, c/a}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);
```

Is there a direct way to do this without naming the nodes and drawing the lines manually?

edit: On the left is the first snippet and on the right the second, I want to have the right one:
[image: pathexample.png]

Comment: `naming the nodes` is a convenient way! other ways is more complex I think

Comment: I don't know if I understood properly your question, so are you looking for something like this? https://postimg.cc/WFZH113f/3ed0c296

Comment: @LukeTheWolf yes, that is exactly what I am looking for (and approximately what the second snippet produces)

Comment: @MartinR I have used a different structure, but if you just need the node connection it could be useful too. So tell me if you want me to post it anyway

Comment: @LukeTheWolf I just added a picture of the problem. As long as it is simpler than naming the nodes and also scales to larger geometries, I am interested

Comment: Ok, let me rewrite this, then I post it

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw}]
\draw node (1) {1} --++(-60:2cm) node (2) {2} --++(180:2cm) node (3){3} (1)--(2)--(3)--(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm used to write automata, I found that was easier to draw a triangle in this way:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
        scale = 1,transform shape]

  \node[state] (1) {$1$};
  \node[state] (2) [below left of=1] {$2$};
  \node[state] (3) [below right of=1] {$3$};

  \path [-] (1) edge (2)
        [-] (2) edge (3)
        [-] (1) edge (3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It probably doesn't solve the problem the same way you were asking for, but as we discussed in the comment, this is how I would solve it.

In any case, you can take a cue from this and rewrite it in some other ways!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will get that naming the nodes is a convenient feature when you are more familiar with TikZ.

In the following, all nodes have no name.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{1.5}   
\draw (90:\r)--(210:\r)--(-30:\r)--cycle;
\path[nodes={draw,circle,fill=white}]
(90:\r) node{1}
(210:\r) node{2}
(-30:\r) node{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```